# Convertir de String dd-mm-yyyy a Date en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito convertir a `Date` una fecha que viene como `String`.

Ya viene formateada desde MySQL a `%d-%m-%Y`, pero ésta en la vista con jQuery me la reconoce como un String.

Recibo datos convertidos a `%d-%m-%Y` en PHP (CodeIgneiter):

```
$this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(auto.fecha_reserva, '%d-%m-%Y') as fecha", FALSE);
$this->db->from('auto');
$datos=$this->db->get();
return $datos->result();
```

Obtengo los datos:

```
$.each(obj.resultado, function (ind, elem) { 
ejemplo : alert(typeof("30-10-2017")); //viene desde la query
 alert(typeof(elem.fecha));//retorna un String "dd-mm-yyyy
 //necesito que elem.fecha sea un date en dd-mm-yyyy 
 //lo ideal seria formatearla sin uso de plugins

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Del string que tienes en `elem.fecha`, necesitas extraer los valores de día, mes y año por separado. 
Para tu ejemplo `30-10-2017` puedes obtenerlos llamando a la función `split("-")`, la cual devolverá un arreglo con cada elemento de la fecha:

```
var arregloFecha = elem.fecha.split("-");
```

Para contruir el objeto de tipo `Date` puedes utilizar el constructor `new Date(anio, mes, dia)`.
El campo mes puede tener un valor entre 0 y 11, en donde 0 representa Enero y 11 Diciembre. Por ello es necesario restar 1 del valor de mes obtenido en `arregloFecha` antes de utilizarlo en el constructor.

Tu código completo quedaría así:

```
var arregloFecha = elem.fecha.split("-");
var anio = arregloFecha[2];
var mes = arregloFecha[1] - 1;
var dia = arregloFecha[0];

var fecha = new Date(anio, mes, dia); // fecha será de tipo Date
```

Más información sobre `Date` en este [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Recuerda que `año` es un nombre de variable válido en JavaScript. No necesitas [transliterar](https://dle.rae.es/transliterar) el nombre o usar `anio` ya que [la totalidad de los conjuntos  de letras mayúsculas y minúsculas (`Lc` y `Ll`) de Unicode están soportados](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-10.3). Hoy en día la práctica totalidad de navegadores web siguen el estándar ECMAScript, por lo que no tendrás los problemas de compatibilidad en los nombres de variables que hubo en el pasado.

Answer (score 1):

### Formatos de fechas

Deberías acostumbrarte a trabajar internamente **SIEMPRE** con fechas en formato **aaaa-mm-dd hh:mm:ss** (y, a ser posible, en UTC) y/o [ISO 8601](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

MySQL muestra los datos de fechas en ese formato ([ver documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)) y es capaz de interpretar sin problemas ISO 8601. En JavaScript el formato de intercambio de fechas es una versión simplificada de ISO 8601 ([ver documentación](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)).

Es decir, si nos evitamos convertir las fechas a formato local conseguiremos que:

- JavaScript entiende el valor devuelto por MySQL sin necesidad de conversión o tratamiento de la cadena.
- MySQL entiende el valor entregado por JavaScript sin necesidad de hacer una conversión o preparación de los datos.
- Ni JavaScript ni MySQL podrían interpretar erróneamente la fecha. No habrá confusión entre meses y días como podría ocurrir en formatos dd-mm-aaaa y mm-dd-aaaa.

### Codificación de los datos de fecha

No existe ninguna manera de hacer que una clase `Date` se represente en JSON de una manera tal que posteriormente se interprete de manera automática de nuevo como una instancia de `Date`, por lo que siempre será necesaria la intervención de código que realice dicha transformación.

### Código

Basándonos en estos puntos tu código PHP debería ser:

```
<?php
$this->db->select("fecha_reserva fecha", FALSE);
$this->db->from('auto');
$datos = $this->db->get();
return $datos->result();
```

Y el código JavaScript:

```
obj.resultado.map(
  elem => new Date(elem.fecha)
);
```

El resultado será una matriz de fechas.

Si quieres mantener la propiedad `fecha`, entonces deberías usar:

```
obj.resultado.map(
  elem => {
    return { fecha: new Date(elem.fecha) };
  }
);
```

Por último, indicarte que no necesitas hacer uso de jQuery en este proceso.

Answer (score -1):

## **[Date()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp)**

Utilizando `new Date(número)`, crea un nuevo objeto de fecha como *hora cero* más el número.

*La hora cero es 01 enero 1970 00:00:00 UTC.*

El número se especifica en milisegundos.

```js
var dateVar = "2010-10-30";
console.log("String: "+dateVar);
var d=new Date(dateVar);
console.log("Date: "+d);
```

Te añado algo de código. Para que veas como funciona el tema de las conversiones. Frente a cada dato viene el tipo.

```js
var dateVar = "2010-10-30";
console.log(jQuery.type(dateVar)+": "+dateVar);

var d = new Date(dateVar);
console.log(jQuery.type(d)+": "+d);

var n = d.toLocaleDateString();
console.log(jQuery.type(n)+": "+n);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: como obtengo la conversion al usar new Date('30-10-2017'); ? a formato dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: ¿como que como la obtienes? la variable con formato fecha ya lo tienes para usar. De todas formas... ¿en que y donde quieres usarlo? igual vamos a verlo mas rapido :P

Comment: al ejecutar tu codigo retorno "Date: Fri Oct 29 2010 21:00:00 GMT-0300 (CLST)" de una fecha se puede transformar a dd-mm-yyyy ?

Comment: Ya que tienes un objeto Date puedes hacer uso de sus funciones, para imprimir tu fecha en formato `dd-mm-yyyy` puedes hacer lo siguiente `console.log(d.getDate() + '-' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + d.getFullYear())`
Ojo: Date.getMonth() regresa valores de 0 a 11 por lo que debemos sumarle 1

Comment: si quieres imprimir tu fecha en formato dd-mm-yyyy eso termina siendo un string. De una forma u otra. Para mostrarlo "String" y para trabajar con ello "Date". @JavierAntonioAguayoAguilar

Answer (score -1):

Podrías considerar crear un método que recibe como parámetro la cadena y te devuelva un objeto `Date`.

Por ejemplo, para fecha con formato: `30-10-2017`

```js
function toDate(cadenaFecha){

  var patron = /^(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{4})$/;
  var arrayFecha = cadenaFecha.match(patron);
  var fecha = new Date(arrayFecha[3], arrayFecha[2] - 1, arrayFecha[1]);

  return fecha;
  
}

console.log(toDate("30-10-2017"));
```

Comment: El sigue con la misma. Quiere un date con formato dd-mm-yyyy. Que es un string. De todas formas, si usas toLocaleDateString te vas ahorrar un trozo.

Comment: @GDP no entenderte, ¿Porqué me ahorraría un "trozo" usar [toLocaleDateString](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocaledatestring.asp)?. Solo puse mi pregunta para convertir una cadena a fecha. Ahora que no entienda que cosa es un objeto Date ya es otra cosa.

Comment: Vale, se me ha ido. De todas formas, si queires convertir una cadena a fecha, te vale con poner Date(cadena) ¿no?

Comment: Para el caso de la respuesta uso el inicializador `new Date(año, mes, dia)`, debido a que obtengo la información de la cadena.